# Backbone listenTo does not fire jquery function as a handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have problem with Backbone's events system.

**Is it possible to pass jquery function as callback directly?**

Following code does not fire show/hide methods:

```
initialize: function () {
  this.render();
  this.logoutButton = $('#logout-button');
  this.logoutButton.hide();
  this.listenTo(this.model, 'loginSuccessEvent', this.logoutButton.show);
  this.listenTo(this.model, 'logoutSuccessEvent', this.logoutButton.hide);
},
```

But if I change it to this, it works perfectly:

```
initialize: function () {
  this.render();
  this.logoutButton = $('#logout-button');
  this.logoutButton.hide();
  this.listenTo(this.model, 'loginSuccessEvent', this.showButton);
  this.listenTo(this.model, 'logoutSuccessEvent', this.hideButton);
},

showButton: function () {
  this.logoutButton.show();
},

hideButton: function () {
  this.logoutButton.hide();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo):

> **listenTo** `object.listenTo(other, event, callback)`
>   [...]
>   The `callback` will always be called with `object` as context.

So when you say this:

```
this.listenTo(this.model, 'loginSuccessEvent', this.logoutButton.show);
```

you're really saying:

```
var show = this.logoutButton.show;
this.listenTo(this.model, 'loginSuccessEvent', show);
```

And then Backbone will call `show` more or less like this:

```
your_view.show(arg, ...);
// Or internally:
show.apply(your_view, arguments);
```

so when `show` (which is jQuery's `show`) gets called, its `this` will be your view rather than `logoutButton`. Remember that `this` inside a JavaScript function depends on how the function is called rather than where it is defined (except for bound functions of course).

You have some options:

1. Use your `showButton` and `hideButton` functions.
2. Use an anonymous function:

   ```
   this.listenTo(this.model, 'loginSuccessEvent', function() {
       this.logoutButton.show();
   });
   ```
3. Use a [bound function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

   ```
   this.listenTo(this.model, 'loginSuccessEvent', this.logoutButton.show.bind(this.logoutButton));
   ```

   Careful with this though, `show` will be called with the arguments that `listenTo` would normally use so you might need to supply more arguments to `bind` to avoid confusing `show` and `hide` with arguments they're not expecting.